# How to erase specific labels inside a matplotlib Legend

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm plotting a scatterplot with matplotlib and seaborn. Hhere is my output.

[image: seaborn scatterplot]

As you can see at the right on the legend there are many labels with the same color, I'm trying to erase all the grays but one. Here is my code:

```
background = '#eeeeee'
high_c = '#5a83aa'
low_c = '#e09a67'
neutral_c = '#fff8c2'

palette = {'Western Europe':high_c,
           'North America and ANZ':'#cccccc',
           'Middle East and North Africa':'#cccccc',
           'Latin America and Caribbean':'#cccccc',
           'Central and Eastern Europe':'#cccccc',
           'East Asia':'#cccccc',
           'Southeast Asia':'#cccccc',
           'Commonwealth of Independent States':'#cccccc',
           'Sub-Saharan Africa':low_c,
           'South Asia':'#cccccc'
}

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(10, 5),dpi=120)
fig.patch.set_facecolor(background) # figure background color
ax.set_facecolor(background)

# plots
sns.scatterplot(data=df21, x='Healthy life expectancy', y='Ladder score',
                hue=df21['Regional indicator'],
                palette=palette, alpha=0.95,ec='black',
                size=df21["Logged GDP per capita"]*1000, legend=True, sizes=(5, 500))

# Axes
ax.set_xlabel("Healthy Life Expectancy",fontfamily='sans serif',loc='left',color='gray')
ax.set_ylabel("Happiness Index Score",fontfamily='sans serif',loc='top',color='gray')
ax.tick_params(axis = 'both', which = 'major', labelsize = 10)

for s in ["top","right","left"]:
    ax.spines[s].set_visible(False)

# Annotations    
ax.text(45,9.2,'Happiness Score, Life Expectancy, and GDP per Capita',
        fontfamily='sans serif',fontweight='normal',fontsize=17,weight='bold',color='#323232')

# Legend
L = ax.legend(frameon=False,loc="upper center", bbox_to_anchor=(1.25, 0.8), ncol= 1)
plt.setp(L.texts, family='sans serif')
L.get_frame().set_facecolor('none')
L.get_texts()[2].set_text('Others')
L.get_texts()[3].set_text('')
L.get_texts()[4].set_text('')
L.get_texts()[5].set_text('')

ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='both',left=False, bottom=False,labelbottom=True) 

plt.show()
```

I figure how to change the text on a label with: L.get_texts()[2].set_text('Others'), but can't find how to delete it, I would like a Legend with just 'Western Europe', 'Sub-Saharan Africa' and 'Other'.

I think that maybe with the 'handler_map', but I can't figure out how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The legend automatically ignores all labels that start with `'_'`.
An idea is to rename all grey regions to start with a `'_'`.

Your code is missing reproducible data, but the changes could look like:

```py
df21['Regional indicator']
new_name = {month: '_' + month if color == '#cccccc' else month for month, color in palette.items()}
new_name['North America and ANZ'] = 'other'
df21['Regional indicator'] = df21['Regional indicator'].map(new_names)
new_palette = {new_name[month]: color for month, color in palette.items()}

sns.scatterplot(data=df21, x='Healthy life expectancy', y='Ladder score',
                hue='Regional indicator',
                palette=new_palette, alpha=0.95, ec='black',
                size=df21["Logged GDP per capita"] * 1000, legend=True, sizes=(5, 500))
```

Here is a self-contained example using seaborn's flights dataset.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

flights = sns.load_dataset('flights')
palette = {'Jan': 'crimson', 'Feb': 'limegreen', 'Mar': 'blue', 'Apr': 'gold', 'May': 'purple', 'Jun': '#cccccc',
           'Jul': '#cccccc', 'Aug': '#cccccc', 'Sep': '#cccccc', 'Oct': '#cccccc', 'Nov': '#cccccc', 'Dec': '#cccccc'}
new_name = {month: '_' + month if color == '#cccccc' else month for month, color in palette.items()}
new_name['Jun'] = 'other'
flights['month'] = flights['month'].map(new_names)
new_palette = {new_name[month]: color for month, color in palette.items()}
sns.scatterplot(data=flights, x='year', y='passengers', hue='month', palette=new_palette)
plt.show()
```

[image: removing some hue labels]

Comment: Thanks you it  worked! you made it look so easy, I was able to find a solution, but yours looks cleaner. My solution was to use:  < handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels() >  and the edit handles:   < delete = 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
handles = [i for j, i in enumerate(handles) if j not in delete] >  and use that for the Legend:  < L = ax.legend(handles=handles, >

Comment: I would but I don't have enough reputation to cast a vote, sorry.